# Sidekiq procesa unos registros y otros no. (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

El problema es el siguiente, se realiza la carga de un archivo csv al portal y la evaluación de los datos del archivo se realiza en un thread con Sidekiq. El detalle consiste en que procesa una cantidad de registros de ese archivo de manera correcta y los últimos registros no los llega a procesar, ya que al parecer los parámetros que debe leer de los registros guardados en base de datos no los sigue leyendo o no los extrae de manera correcta. Hace el llamado a las clases pero no tiene los parámetros para ser procesados. Por lo tanto me da errores de que esos campos no pueden ser procesados por estar vacíos.

No estoy seguro si es por algún timer de alguna gema que no me permite hacer la lectura de los datos mientras el thread se ejecuta o que proceso estará truncando la ejecución de esos datos.

Uno de los problemas es que en variadas ocasiones sidekiq se vuelve inestable y es necesario bajar y levantar el proceso para que siga trabajando de manera normal.

Comment: Es imposible "adivinar" si no agregas un código o algo que ayude a ver que problema puedas tener

Comment: creo que falta que muestres el código y explicar mejor el problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El caso tenía que ver con problemas de la bd, más que todo con problemas de hdd donde se alojaba y operaba la bd. Al haber latencia en la lectura de registros a la hora del proceso de sidekiq provocaba inconsistencias en la operación de los datos. El proovedor cambió el hdd y se hizo la migración de la bd y todo funcionó normalmente.